# noexcept expression vs type traits

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning how to use conditional `noexcept` and come across this problem. Suppose I have a class:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(T&& value) noexcept(/* ??? */)
        : value_(std::move(value))
    {}

private:
    T value_;
};
```

For the `/* ??? */` part, I thought we can use either `noexcept(T(std::move(value)))` or `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value`, until I stumbled upon [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible#Notes).

So if I use `noexcept(noexcept(T(std::move(value))))`, strictly speaking I'm saying that "this constructor is `noexcept` iff constructing *and destructing* a `T` is `noexcept`"?

Although destructors that throw should be put on fire and burned.

Comment: Can you work around this using e.g. `noexcept(new T(std::move(value)))` or someting? Since it is an unevaluated expression it's not actually allocating anything but also it should specifically "leak" and so the dtor should not be involved... I guess you might need to use a no-throw version of new though, since you don't want to detect `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question, see also [this language defect discussion](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2116). From its name it appears clear that `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` *should* only relate to the constructibiliry from an rvalue (but in practice may also relate to the destruction), while `noexcept(T(std::move(value)))` always relates to both construction and destruction.

So, in your case, the most save way, avoiding the unresolved issue of the `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` traits, is to use placement new, avoiding the issue with `std::bad_alloc` (mentioned in Chris Beck's comment), and, similarly, use `T`'s desctructor for the wrapper's destructor.

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(T&& value) noexcept(new(nullptr) T(std::move(value)))
        : value_(std::move(value))
    {}
    ~Wrapper() noexcept(noexcept(value_.T::~T()))
    {}
private:
    T value_;
};
```

Comment: _"it's clear that `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` should only relate to the constructor"_ -- that's not clear at all, the issue is unresolved, and it's certainly not true that there is a clear consensus that the submitter's expectation is correct, or that there's any defect in the standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely point taken. I have edited the question. I would think that a C++ standard construct should do what it says on the tin, i.e. in this case tests only whether a type has a no-throw move constructor, but nothing else.

Comment: But the trait is not "has nothrow move constructor" (see [N3142](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html) for why it isn't that). Instead it tells you whether creating an object from an rvalue can throw, which is not the same. And for most cases where you want to know if creating it throws, you also want to know if destroying it throws,  because it's no good optimising something like the internals of a container for elements with non-throwing moves if their destructors can throw.

Comment: Also, the MoveConstructible concept that the trait is related to (but not identical to) subsumes the Destructible concept. A type which is not Destructible is not MoveConstructible. So "is MoveConstructible" means "can be constructed from an rvalue, and is destructible", and "is nothrow MoveConstructible" means "can be constructed from an rvalue, and is destructible, and those operations don't throw". So I still take issue with your claim that "From its name it appears clear ..." because you seem to think the name is "has nothrow move constructor" rather than "is nothrow move constructible".

Comment: @JonathanWakely The name certainly does not relate to destruction and the traits shouldn't either (for otherwise it's confusing and unclear – there are cases where one wants a traits solely on the construction). Thus, the remaining issue is the distinction between 'is constructible' and 'has constructor'. Okay, we want to know if `T(std::move(value))` works and will not throw, but **not** if the destruction of the resulting object may throw.

Comment: The name relates to MoveConstructible, and that subsumes Destructible.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I understand that, but take issue with this: it's unclear and confusing. There should then be a concept MoveConstructibleAndDescructible and similar for the traits. There are cases, where one may want to differentiate these things.

Comment: @JonathanWakely But CopyConstructible subsumes MoveConstructible and yet `is_[meow_]copy_constructible` doesn't check move construction :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely IMHO, traits should do what they say on the tin, nothing less and nothing more. Everything else is a recipe for confusion, buggy code, and disaster.

Comment: @T.C. yes, that's why I said `is_move_constructible` is related to (but not identical to) MoveConstructible. It's still closer to MoveConstructible than to "has move constructor" because there are many types that are MoveConstructible, and for which `is_move_constructible` is true, but which don't have a move constructor.

Comment: @Walter, there are cases where you want to distinguish them, but they are uncommon (throwing destructors are uncommon, and non-Destructible types are rarer still). The concepts and the traits correspond to the properties required in the Standard Library (which are also the ones more commonly needed in user code too). If you want a different trait for different cases, write one. `std::is_move_constructible` does what it's specified to do in the standard, and IMHO that's not a defect.